# How do I access rails 3 app's environment variables from within the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that needs to respond to different url's. I am using Nginx and want to set the environment variable for host, but I don't know how to set it or get that env variable back out in the controller. For example, I want something like this...

```
http://sillyname.com/page_name/home
```

nginx sets the ENV['HOST'] = $host

and rails routes to page controller action => show, params page_name => home. Then in the controllers show action

```
def show
  @website = Website.find_by_host_name(ENV['HOST'])
  @page = @website.page.where("title",params[:page_name])
  ...
end
```

My specific questions are:

1. what directive do I use in nginx do I use to set this variable, or is it already accessible in a rails 3 app?
2. how do I access the ENV variable in the app to correctly query the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the information out of the `request` object in your controller. Please check specifically:

```
request.host
```

or investigate into

```
request.env
```

Comment: do you have a good resource for understanding the request obj.? None of my rails books have anything on if...

Comment: A good start is the API documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html